# Should we have separate tags for each major Final Fantasy game?

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

Seeing as we seem to be accepting Final Fantasy tagged plot-based questions, and the fact that each game is in its own self contained universe - should we change the existing [final-fantasy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy) tag into several?

Example: [final-fantasy-vi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-vi),[final-fantasy-vii](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-vii),[final-fantasy-viii](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-viii),[final-fantasy-x](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-x)[final-fantasy-xii](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xii),[final-fantasy-xiii](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiii), etc.

And perhaps keep the [final-fantasy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy) tag for questions that are about the series as a whole or do not fit comfortably into the series (spin off titles like crystal chronicles for example)

What are opinions on this? I personally can see myself using these split ones as favourite tags as I have played through some, but not all of the games.

It's still a new enough set of questions, but we could pre-emptively change this rather than having to go back and fix it

Comment: I remember that tag separation is done according to expert separation. So if the people who know about thing A might not know anything about thing B, it's probably a good idea to use separate tags. But FF game series players are probably aware of what's going on in all the games, so probably keep it all under one tag.

Comment: I don't think someone who has played FF7 and FF8 nessicarily knows anything about the plotlines in FF9. There is some knowledge that copies over, but most of this is game mechanics and an occasional chocobo

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Good point, I played FF6, 7, 8, 9, and 10, but I've never finished the first five and I've never gone near any of the newer ones, so I for one wouldn't have the slightest idea how to answer a question about, say, FF12.

Answer (score 5):

Final Fantasy is pretty far from our core expertise. It's also not something that I expect we'll get a lot more questions on, and I wouldn't personally encourage most people to ask their questions here. It seems to usually fit better on [SFF](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) or [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) in terms of expertise. That doesn't mean that it's off-topic here, but it's a niche topic with better coverage elsewhere (in much the same way that Fullmetal Alchemist is on-topic on both SFF and here but is covered much more thoroughly here).

Hence, for the forseeable future, I don't see a need for separate tags. More tags have an intrinsic cost in that they make it harder to find questions. There's little benefit unless the tags are big enough to be worth splitting (and have different enough expertise to merit a split). Broader tags also cover more, which means new users won't need to create a new tag. If we end up in a situation with a dozen questions on each of the FF games (like Arqade has) then it's worth thinking about a split, but right now, I think  keeping a single [final-fantasy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy) tag is probably fine.